# Invoking Kafka Producer Interceptor and Logs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluence-rest-api

We are using Confluent JDBC Connector to ingest data to Kafka.

We have setup CustomInterceptor by setting following property:

```
producer.interceptor.classes=CustomInterceptor
```

in

```
connect-*.properties
```

But it does not seem to get invoked.

Another problem is that we are not able to see INFO logs which we are adding to our CustomInterceptor.

We are looking into following logs:

```
confluent log connect

confluent log kafka
```

In this case,

1. Is there anything else we need to set up as property to get the CustomInterceptor working ?
2. Where do we see the logs from CustomInterceptor ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How are you invoking Kafka Connect? I'm guessing `confluent start connect`? Which configuration file are you putting the `producer.interceptor.classes` setting in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. Earlier i think one of the confluent components was not getting started correctly and hence the failure.